# phantomjs - store and send cookies

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS as follows to retrieve and parse data from a website.

```
const phantom = require('phantom');
const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'

let _ph, _page, _outObj;
phantom.create()
.then( (ph) => {
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
}).then( (page) => {
    _page = page;
    return page.open(url);
}).then( (status) => {
    console.log(`Status: ${status}`);
    return _page.property('content');
}).then( (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
}).catch( (e) => console.log(e));
```

What I need to do also is to store the cookie send by the server and include them in subsequent requests to the server - how do I go about it ?

Comment: What is your node.js version?

Comment: node version is v8.9.4 and `"phantom": "^4.0.12"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS is capable of storing and loading cookies by itself, according to [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) there is a cli option for that:

> `--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt` specifies the file name to store the persistent Cookies

So with `phantom` node module you pass this option upon browser creation:

```
phantom.create(['--cookies-file=/path/to/cookies.txt']).then(...)
```

Comment: could you add the documentation link as well ? Also how about `Etag`

Comment: Added the link to the docs, don't know about eTag though, if it's important it's better to use a mitm proxy like Fiddler and check to be sure.